# How to send an error if someone inputs a string into a double and after an error message is sent, they do it again

Tags: c#

This is the code I have. It works and sends an error to the user when they input something other than a number. What I need to figure out is how to send the same error if they try to enter a string again.

```
Console.WriteLine("Type in a number and then press enter:");
try
{
    num2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
}
catch
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please Enter a valid numerical value!");
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid number and then press enter:");
    num2 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
double result;
do
{
    Console.Write("Type in a number and then press enter: ");
}
while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result));
Console.WriteLine($"Thanks! {result}");
```

Comment: This is better than letting the conversion run into an exception.

Answer (score 3):

You should use [`double.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8), which returns a `bool` indicating whether or not the parsing was successful, and which sets an `out` parameter to the converted value. Then you can do something like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Type in a number and then press enter:");

double userInput;

while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out userInput)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please Enter a valid numerical value!");
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid number and then press enter:");
}

// After the above loop, the variable 'userInput' will contain the user's number
```

This is more intentional than using `try/catch` to do input validation. For more reading, see: [Why are Exceptions said to be so bad for Input Validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410558/why-are-exceptions-said-to-be-so-bad-for-input-validation)

Comment: To be fair having a try/catch is not "expensive".  throwing an exception especially one that is deeply nested is "expensive". (Though either way when based on user input the overhead of the exception stack rollback is less than the expense on waiting for a user to a button.)

Answer (score 2):

Create a boolean `verifiedNumber` then create a `while` loop

```cs
while(!verifiedNumber) {
   Console.WriteLine("Type in a number and then press enter:");
   try { 
      num2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine()); 
      verifiedNumber = true;
   } 
   catch { 
      Console.WriteLine("Please Enter a valid numerical value!"); 
   }
}
```

Comment: That will loop forever until he actually enters a number.

Comment: If the op would want to only allow a certain number of attempts, they can add an int for attempts and check if it's less than that

Comment: actually i take it back.  I missed your console readline that would pause it until he enters.  It looks good to me.

Answer (score 0):

As another althernative you can use `for` loop:

```
double result;

for(; ; )
{
    Console.WriteLine("Type in a number and then press enter:");

    if(!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result)){
        Console.WriteLine("Please Enter a valid numerical value!");
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid number and then press enter:");
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine($"Result = {result}");
```