# C# Catch exception or validate parameters beforehand

Tags: c#, performance, exception

This is a question about exception handling and prevention.

```
public static string PathCombineNoEx(string path1, string path2)
{
   if (path1 == null || path2 == null /*Either validate here*/)
   {
      return null;
   }

   try
   {
      return System.IO.Path.Combine(path1, path2);
   }
   catch (ArgumentException /*or catch here*/)
   {
      return null;
   }
}
```

Since exceptions are an enormous hit on performance we should try to minimize the chance for exceptions to be thrown. In the following example I've eliminated the chance that `Path.Combine` could throw an `ArgumentnullException`. This was very easy to do and does almost not affect performance in any way. However, `Path.Combine` also throws an `ArgumentException` if one of the two parameter strings contains any invalid character provided by `GetInvalidPathChars`.

1. Now, would you recommend to catch this as I did or would you really check for invalid chars before calling the `Path.Combine`?
2. What about a general recommendation that can be applied to most situations.
3. Maybe there is a Microsoft article about that?

`Path.Combine` documentation:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx

The .NET Reference Source:
http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/path.cs,2d7263f86a526264

Microsft performance tip (see chapter *Throw fewer exceptions*):
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973839.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Catching exceptions is *slow* since exception throwing does *stack trace*.
2. Catching exceptions is less readable; it's a kind of notorious *goto*: if something has happened then *goto catch*.

That's why I vote for *validation*:

```
   if (path1 == null) 
     return null;
   if (path2 == null) 
     return null; 

   //TODO: put other validations here, e.g. Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()  

   return System.IO.Path.Combine(path1, path2);
```

And catch exceptions for *exceptional* cases only:

```
   try {
     // I can't validate this, since just after I've finished it and ready to read 
     // someone can
     //   - delete/rename the file
     //   - change permissions
     //   - lock file (e.g. start writing to it) 
     String data = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\MyData.txt"); 
     ...
   }
   catch (IOException e) {
     ... 
   }
```

Comment: @Noël Widmer: Yes I didn't *catch* `ArgumentException` of `Path.Combine`: instead, I suggesting validation: check for `Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()`, `Path.GetInvalidPathChars()` and other if required

Comment: I know how to do it. Just wanted to know if you'd still validate it. thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Exceptions, as the term says, are meant to handle unexpected situations. I vote to handle foreseeable cases in code beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions can hit performance.

If it's an API,

```
public static string PathCombineNoEx(string path1, string path2)
 {
  if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path1))
  {
    throw new ArgumentnullException(path1);
  }

 //Same goes for Path2

 return System.IO.Path.Combine(path1, path2);
}
```

Otherwise, Dmitry's answer will do.

Helpful SO posts:

[Business Objects, Validation And Exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88541/business-objects-validation-and-exceptions)

[Why are Exceptions said to be so bad for Input Validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410558/why-are-exceptions-said-to-be-so-bad-for-input-validation)

Comment: just as a sidenote, IsNullOrWhiteSpace returns bool and your code checks it against null